# All elements in a group with certain order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I'd like for some help with this question.

Let ${ G = \mathbb{Z}_{10} \oplus  \mathbb{Z}_{12}}$.

1. What is the maximal order of an element in that group?

   My answer: $O(G) = l.c.m.[10,12] = 60$. (Does this answer correct?)
2. Find all the elements in $G$ of order 8 and all the elements in $G$ of order 6.

How can I find all the elements from the second question?

Comment: is the second question meant to be asking to find all elements of order 8 twice?

Comment: @Alexandros Updated. Thanks

Comment: In second question you have to find all pairs (a, b) $\in G$ such that lcm ( order(a) , order(b) ) = 8.

Comment: @SunnyRathore Thanks! Is there efficient way to do it rather than calculate them one by one?

Comment: May be you can do counting smartly but i don't see any quicker way.

Comment: the order of an element divides the maximum order. therefore no elements of order $8$